# Replace a string in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the below text to replace in sql server. Is there any query to do so? The text is found in a column of a table.

Text before replace:

```
[demo].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table]
```

I want to replace the text and result should appear like this:

```
[[demo]].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table]]]
```

Comment: could you cite some more examples?

Comment: Where do you want to replace? an procedure? Try to be more clear

Comment: TExt where? In a data field or in code (like a SP)?

Comment: the value is stored in a variable and that variable should be replaced

Comment: [demo].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table] is stored in a variable. the query should check the format and replace the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this !

```
declare @a as varchar(100)
set @a ='[demo].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table]'
select QUOTENAME(@a)
```

## <kbd>[see it live](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17290)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace text in a column, for a row, like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET fld = REPLACE(fld,
    '[demo].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table]',
    '[[demo]].[demo_df__table_list__enum_table]]]')
WHERE [some condition here]
```

---

**UPDATE:** I see that you can use `QUOTENAME` as shown below, that's a good approach, but it still does you no good without the `UPDATE` statement. So the query would be:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET fld = REPLACE(fld, fld, QUOTENAME(fld))
WHERE [some condition here]
```

Comment: @user3425160, well now that the OP has updated their question I now know what text they are trying to replace with what. But the OP needs to leverage the `REPLACE` command to update a field in a table with new text. I'm not sure how it *doesn't* answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace is a function which takes three parametere:    i;e Replace(Column Name,string literal to be replaced in Column,string literal to placed.)
For examples G_DATE is Column
2015-03-09
2015-03-09
2015-03-09
2015-03-10
2015-03-10
2015-03-10
2015-03-12
2015-03-12
2015-03-12

UPDATE table
SET G_DATE = REPLACE(G_DATE,'15','16')
will give us

2016-03-09
2016-03-09
2016-03-09
2016-03-10
2016-03-10
2016-03-10
2016-03-12
2016-03-12
2016-03-12